# Show that $\mu(f_n^+) \rightarrow \mu(f^+) $ and $\mu(f_n^-) \rightarrow \mu(f^-) $, using Fatou's Lemma.

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I'm starting learning about Fatou's lemma. How would you apply it to solve the following problem:

Let $g^+ = max (g,0)$ and $g^- = max (-g,0)$.

Let $f_n$ be integrable on measure space with measure $\mu$.
Assume $f_n \rightarrow f$ almost everywhere and $\mu(|f_n|) \rightarrow \mu(|f|) $.
Show that $\mu(f_n^+) \rightarrow \mu(f^+) $ and $\mu(f_n^-) \rightarrow \mu(f^-) $.

Comment: Does is a measure function a measure? If so, what does $\mu(|f|)$ mean?

Comment: $\mu$ is a measure. edited.

Comment: So what does $\mu(|f|)$ mean?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese $\mu\left(f\right)$ is a (nice) abbreviation of $\int fd\mu$ so
$\mu\left(\left|f\right|\right)=\int\left|f\right|d\mu=\int f^{+}d\mu+\int f^{-}d\mu=\mu\left(f^{+}\right)+\mu\left(f^{-}\right)$. This way measure $\mu$ takes values on functions instead of sets
and is linear upto a certain level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fatou's lemma claims that $\text{liminf} \int{f_n}\ge\int\liminf {f_n}$ where $f_n\ge0$ pointwise

According to your assumption $f_n\to f$ a.e.,we have $f_n^+\to f^+$ a.e. and similarly for $f^-$

By Fatou's lemma you have $\liminf\int f_n^+ \ge \int f^+$ and
$\liminf\int f_n^- \ge \int f^- $

$\int|f_n| \rightarrow \int |f| $ shows$\int f_n^+ +\int f_n^- \rightarrow \int f^+ +\int f^- $

But you know $\int f_n^+\ge\liminf\int f_n^+ $. So you arrive at the conclusion.

($\lim(\int f_n^++\int f_n^-)\ge\liminf \int f_n^++\liminf \int f_n^- \ge \int \liminf f_n^++\int \liminf f_n^-=\int f^++\int f^-$ so each step is equallity, especially the middle one is what the conclusion claims)

Hope it helps.